# HTML 5 date input type, button to expand calendar dropdown appears below input field? CSS issue?

Tags: css, html

I think there is something that has been done to the CSS in my web app that is affecting the input type = date. As per the image below, the dropdown for the calendar appears below the input field which is obviously not where it should be. Even when I set the width of the input field to very large, which clearly has enough room for the calendar drop down, it appears below still. I can't figure out what in the CSS has changed to affect it like this and I've been playing around with it for hours. Does anyone know what it might be?

As an FYI, I use bootstrap and am using Chrome version 25 on Windows.

As far as I can tell this is the css that I've written that affects it. Note that the first 4 below target input fields, and thus target this date input field. The rest are affecting it through various other CSS (i.e. styling tables, etc)

Personally I've played with all of the below settings already and can't seem to figure it out.

```
width:70%;
display:block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
color: #999;
font-size: inherit;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
-webkit-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
height: 20px;
padding: 4px 6px;
margin-bottom: 9px;
line-height: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 0;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
border-spacing: 2px;
border-color: gray;
```

[image]

Comment: did you try changing the values of padding, height or width ? and moreover do you have any debugger ? like I use Firebug for firefox

Comment: Your Chrome version is old. Do you still have the issue with the latest version (26.0)?

Comment: @Deepanshu yup I used the chrome's developer tools to play around with all of the above settings.

Comment: @int32_t I'll update it now and see but I'm hoping that isn't the issue because V 25 is still relatively up-to-date...

Comment: markup? make a fiddle